# User can hasMany Conversations through 2 foreign keys

Tags: php, laravel

Part of my application is private messages between 2 users.

I have a `converstations` table that has `user1` and `user2` foreign keys.

Now I wanna have an eloquent function in the User model where I can get his conversations. But a user could be `user1` or `user2` in any given conversation.

This function for example will only account to conversations where I happen to be user1.

```
public function conversations()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Conversation', 'user1');
}
```

So how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A suggestion into your approach would be to store the users of a `Conversation` in a pivot table. So a `Conversation` can have more than, in your case, two users. This will lead to easier queries and more expension options. In that case you would just have to do the following:

```php
return $this->belongsToMany(Conversation::class);
```

Check the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) for more info.

**Addition to comment**

If you really need this table to have those two columns people would normally do the following:

```php
return $this->hasMany(Conversation::class, 'user1')->orWhere('user2', $this->id);
```

However since this is an `orWhere` it could get you incorrect records. This query is executed:

```sql
select * from "conversations" where "conversations"."user1" = 1 and "conversations"."user1" is not null or "user2" = 1
```

But there I have found another way. There is a [`noConstraints`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/Relation.php#L80) method on the [`Relation`](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/Relation.htm) abstract class , from which all relation classes extend, that allows you to modify the whole query:

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;

return HasMany::noConstraints(function () {
    return $this->hasMany(Conversation::class)
        ->where('user1', $this->id)
        ->orWhere('user2', $this->id);
});
```

This will result in the query what you are looking for:

```sql
select * from "conversations" where "user1" = 1 or "user2" = 1
```

I am not sure how this will effect eagerloading and such.

Still I suggest having a pivot table to keep your database/application flexible.

Comment: hmmm, I don't really wanna have a pivot table. Because having more than 2 users just isn't applicable in my case. If it's the only way I guess I'll do it.

Comment: @AdamZahran The answer has been updated with a solution that would fit your requirements.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have learned a thing or two from your answer apart from having my issue resolved.

Answer (score -1):

```
public function conversations()
{
    if(test_for_user1_or_user2())
    { 
        return $this->hasMany(converstations ::class,'user1_id');
    }
    return $this->hasMany(converstations ::class,'user2_id');
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.